# Problemas para validad correctamente un ciclo For en C++

Tags: c++, windows

Hice este programa que inicia con un rectángulo pequeño, y después va imprimiendo otros rectángulos más grandes hasta alcanzar cierto punto, pero se supone que el último for del programa tendría que hacer lo contrario, imprimiendo un rectángulo más grande para después imprimir rectángulos más pequeños, el problema es que el programa sólo hace lo que el primero for le indica, ignorando al segundo for, no se si me faltó añadir algo, ¿alguien sabe qué error puedo tener? 
Aún soy medio manco para programar, disculpen.

```
#include <iostream>                                                       
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <windows.h> 
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void pos(int x,int y){  
      HANDLE hcon;  
      hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);  
      COORD dwPos;  
      dwPos.X = x;  
      dwPos.Y= y;  
      SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);  
 }  

void cuadro(int col1, int col2, int fil1, int fil2) //La función cuadro es la que uso para imprimir todos los cuadrados, solo cambiando las posiciones
{
    pos(col1,fil1);
    cout<<char(201);
    pos(col1,fil2);
    cout<<char(200);
    pos(col2,fil1);
    cout<<char(187);
    pos(col2,fil2);
    cout<<char(188);    

     for (int x=col1+1; x<col2; x++)
    {
        pos(x,fil1);
        cout<<char(205);

        pos(x,fil2);
        cout<<char(205);
    }
    for (int y=fil1+1; y<fil2; y++)
    {
        pos(col1,y);
        cout<<char(186);

        pos(col2,y);
        cout<<char(186);
    }
}

int main(){

    system("color 2E");

    int N=22,N2=23;
    int x1=32,x2=33,y1=100,y2=105;
    int x3=4,x4=49,y3=4,y4=215;

    pos(30,30);
    cout<<"Poner la ventana en pantalla completa para que el programa se pueda apreciar mejor";
    Sleep(5000);
    system("cls");

    for (int i; i<N; i++){ //Este for se encarga de imprimir los cuadros de menor a mayor

SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN);


    Sleep(200);
    cuadro (y1,y2,x1,x2);

    y1=y1-5;
    y2=y2+5;
    x1=x1-1;
    x2=x2+1;

    cout<<"\n\n\n";
}

system("cls");

    for (int j; j<N2; j++){ //Al limpiar la pantalla, este for tendría que comenzar a imprimir cuadros de mayor a menor

SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN);


    Sleep(200);
    cuadro (y3,y4,x3,x4);

    y3=y3+4;
    y4=y4-4;
    x3=x3+1;
    x4=x4-1;

    cout<<"\n\n\n";

    system("cls");
}

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta inicializar la variable

```
for (int j; j<N2; j++){
//       ^ Cual es su valor inicial?
```

Si no inicializas las variables, las mismas empezarán teniendo un valor aleatorio (basura).

```
for (int j=0; j<N2; j++){ // Bucle de 0 a N2-1
```

Nota que los dos últimos bucles conviven actualmente con este problema

Comment: Muchas gracias, no puedo creer que se me haya pasado ese detalle, te agradezco